# pairing blue tooth with user confirmation only

Tags: android

i want to pair Bluetooth with the confirmation from other side only..but i implemented a code and here no confirmation message send to other side ..so now how do i send confirmation message to other before pairing two devices via Bluetooth ..

i use this below code:

```
 private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    // The local server socket
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

        // Create a new listening server socket
        try {
            tmp = mAdapter
                    .listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "listen() failed", e);
        }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

  private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;

    private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
        mmDevice = device;
        BluetoothSocket tmp = null;

        // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the given
        // BluetoothDevice
        try {

            tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "create() failed", e);
        }
        mmSocket = tmp;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectThread");
        setName("ConnectThread");

        // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
        mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
        try {
            // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
            // successful connection or an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            connectionFailed();
            // Close the socket
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                Log.e(TAG,"unable to close() socket during connection failure",
                                e2);
            }
            // Start the service over to restart listening mode
            BluetoothChatService.this.start();
            return;
        }
```

so pls see my code and pls suggest me how to pair 2 devices only when authenticated from remote side...i am using api level 7

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a message to the other device as long as the two devices are not paired, because you need a BluetoothSocket for that, which cannot be obtained unless you have the device's MAC address.
But what's the problem with the pairing request? It will show only the first time, then you can always find the device among the paired devices (mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices()).

Buuut, if it's absolutely necessary for you to get rid of the Pairing request dialog showing at the beginning on the both parts, then you may try use an insecure channel (create the server socket with listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord and the client socket with createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord). The problem here is that you'll have to perform a scan every time you need to connect to a device, as the devices are not paired.

Hope it suits you, goodluck.

Comment: hi gabrela ...is is possible to use istenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord  below api level 10?

Comment: hello gabrjela ..after pairing of 2 devices how to start exchange profile information with authorization request comes in notification..and after accepting it only exchange profile info..i am getting stuck here from 3 days pls help...thanks

Comment: Sorry for the delay ... listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord has been introduced starting with api level 10. About 2nd question, I must say it's not very clear what you're asking, if you still need help please try to be more explicit.